# Android/Java JDBC MySQL - fetch rows - effective algorithm

Tags: java, android, jdbc

I am trying to write an app as an mysql client and I ran into way, which I don't want to follow, because I think, it is not a good one, even if it is possible.

I have JDBC driver in my project, and I want to fetch all rows and write them to user interface - simply draw a data into table.

Everything starts in an usual way:

```
    Statement stmt = DataStore.DataStoreClass.mysqlConn.createStatement() ; 
   /*I have static class for some data*/
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ DataStore.DataStoreClass.currentTable;
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Now, we have some response in

```
while (res.next()) {

}
```

So thats the basics, up to here, everything works fine.
But what is definitely not fine, in res.next() are not data in type, in which are in database.
They are in binary form.
This is how it looks like:

[image]

So. If you want to read lines/columns of table, you need to know one thing - data type.
This is called by

```
res.getMetaData().getColumnTypeName();
```

which returns a string with a name. Unforunately, MySQL uses 22 data types, and at least 5 of them (all variations of int, like tinyint, bigint...) can return just like "tinyint" or "tinyint unsigned". That means, we have 27 things, that can be returned by this command.

So, you have a binary field, and you want to gather data. Well, yes, that is simple... at least if you know, what to expect...

```
 /*This is inside while cycle with res.next()*/
    int columnIndex=1;
    int z = res.getInt(columnIndex);
```

Well, but I dont know, what to expect.
By my way, it would be very complicated.

Lets say, we have already fetched ALL column types used in table, we want to write down, and we have an String array. Also, by that way, we also know the size of table, like number of columns, so we have declared new String array with correct size for future results

And now the programming thing:

```
        while (res.next()){
          String[] row = new String[res.getMetaData.getColumnCount()];
            for(int i=1; i<=res.getMetaData.getColumnCount(); i++){
                String monthString;
                switch (arrayWithDataTypeAtColumPosition[i]) {
                    case "Tinyint":  row[i] = Integer.toString(res.getInt(i));
                             break;
                    case "String":   row[i] = res.getString(i);
                             break;
                    case "Byte":     row[i] = Byte.toString(res.getByte(i));
                             break;
                    /*next all 24 other cases*/
                    }

        sendRowToDisplay(row);
        /*SendRowToDisplay(row); only for illustration purposes only, 
        in real, this is in AsyncTask in doInBackground, 
       so you will use publishProgress(row); to send in to 
       @Override protected void onProgressUpdate (String[] s){}*/

            }
        }
```

And this ... is quite bad. You have the data, but you have to decide, how you convert it to some human readable result.
So my question is:
Is there any way, how to get directly the type without this long long swithch?

Something like (of course this does not exists, it is like to show the way of thinking):

```
while (res.next){
   for(int i=1; i<=res.getMetaData.getColumnCount(); i++){
   res.getDataByMetaDataColumnType().toString();
  }
}
```

What more, this would be very useful for me, because just write down a row is not enough to me. I want to tap the row and in next activity, edit the row, which means, send SELECT * FROM Table WHERE column1=fetchedValue
and then do the same thing, I will have same damn switch for declaring type of TextEdit and the values, which should be loaded into the TextEdits. And then, the next same switch, which will just do the correct data from strings I have in TextEdits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the string representation of all the values in all the columns, you can use the `ResultSet` `getString(int index)` method. The values will be converted to `String` no matter the type of the columns.

Here is an example:

```
    try (Connection con = getDatabaseConnection();) {
        try (Statement st = con.createStatement();) {
            try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TableName");) {
                ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> rows = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                        row.add(rs.getString(i + 1));
                    }
                    rows.add(row);
                }
                System.out.println(rows);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Well, but what if the column in DB is INT? Then, you will have, lets say, value 256888 as INT, as a number. But you will try to write it as STRING.  That means, that the byte flow will be converted into string and not the int. I am not going to go goole the ASCII values of characters, but, just as I am looking at it, Integer.toString(res.getInt(1)) will return 286888, because we have translated bytes into its NUMERIC representation and then thne number into String. res.getString(1) will convert the flow of bytes directly into String, so you will get, for ehample "qx7z"... Am I correct?

Comment: No. The `getString(...)` method returns the `String` representation of the value, for the `int` `256888` the method will return `256888` for a `bit(1)`  type column will return `0` or `1` and so on.

Comment: It works, thanks, at least it will decreases the code length by one damn long switch :)