# Android add TextRows/TextViews programatically by iteration

Tags: android, android-layout

I got through some of guides with creating dynamic objects on layout.

I have a 2D array with data. array[x][y]. each "x" is one TableRow. Each "y" is one Textview inside that row.

The problem is, that the iteration shows only the last row.

The code is:

```
    TableLayout tbl = (TableLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
                for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){
                    TableRow row = new TableRow(activity);
                    row.setId(i);
                    DataStore.DataStoreClass.TableRowID = i;

                    for(int j=1; j<columncount;j++){
                        TextView txt1= new TextView(context);
                        txt1.setText(dataArray[i][j]);
                        row.addView(txt1);
                        }


                    tbl.addView(row);
                }
```

This, in theory, should create textviews, send it to row and then the row into the TableView.
Well, but it shows only the LAST row. In my solution, there should be 330 rows.

What am I doing wrong? Please?

Comment: what are the values of count and column count?

Comment: They are correct, they also depends on previous function, but I checked it debugger. "count" is for "x", that is the number representing number of ROWS. "columncount" stands for number of TextViews inside each TableRow. Columns are OK, the showed last TableRow has the correct things inside it, but even if the first FOR comes 330x, only one row is showed.

Comment: May be `count` it's ok but `columncount` seems to be wrong. It should be set in each iteration of the external loop, something like: `columncount = dataArray[i].length`

Comment: @Zorak and you see only single row?

Comment: @Zorak also what is the dataArray type? Does it return string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems error in your ColumnCount loop. I dont know why one will start loop from 1 instead of 0.

```
              for(int j=1; j<columncount;j++){ // why j=1?
                    TextView txt1= new TextView(context);
                    txt1.setText(dataArray[i][j]);
                    row.addView(txt1);
                    }
```

I have tried your code and it works for me perfectly. I will suggest to print Count and ColumnCount values to get detail!!

Also make sure you are setting char[] or String into txt1.setText(), as if you try setting integer or so, it will crash.

Comment: Well, my topic is related to this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190013/android-java-jdbc-mysql-fetch-rows-effective-algorythm/34190382?noredirect=1#comment56127831_34190382 ... If you say, that it IS WORKING, I will trust you and mark ti as accepted answer, and it seems to be, that the other help is not working and there is some problem with converting my JDBC response from MySQL into an array, which I need to loop through in THIS topic

Comment: Yep, and why from 1 ... JDBC .getString(columnAtPositionInt) starts with 1, not 0 as in array. Well, this was a little mistake and I have corrected it, but still I am able to see only 1 row ..

Comment: Well, yes, I am sorry, it seems to be true, that the other question was answered wrong. I really don't have data in array to show, so, I probably have 330 rows with 6 textViews, but nothing in it to display ... So .. thank you very much for your time anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

//we can create and remove objects dynamically refer the following code:

//Note:Need to create view grop in xml file.(Exactly where you want to add views)

//  Step 1:Create a class A.java

```
public class A extends Activity {

    private ViewGroup container; ArrayList<ViewGroup> list;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.x);
container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.c);
list= new ArrayList<ViewGroup>();
```

// Step 2:Here you need to create method or view directly  as per your //requirement.

// step 3:call the below method in for loop so that every time new view will //be created and all views will be in our control.as per your req

```
addDynamicViews();//we can pass the parameters

}
private void addDynamicViews() {
ViewGroup newView = (ViewGroup)
  LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.b, container,false);    
chieldView_list.add(newView);   
EditText test= (EditText) newView.findViewById(R.id.test);  
//you can add what ever you want
            container.addView(newView, 0);  }
```